# Can I pray on a prayer rug that has Allah’s (swt) name?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, asma-ul-husna

Salaam,

I am a revert and I just took my shahada last month, so I’m still learning how to pray and I bought a prayer rug that has the transliteration of the prayers (it’s not written in Arabic) to help reverts learn, but speaking with someone they said you shouldn’t step on it because it has Allah’s (swt) name on it. The company says it’s allowed because the words are not written in Arabic, is there a ruling on this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all a rug is not necessary for the prayer as our prophet () didn't had this luxury or rarely used it.

However the name of Allah must be respected by any means and in any language by a Muslim.
Allah the Almighty says in 22:30:

> That [has been commanded], and whoever honors the sacred ordinances of Allah - it is best for him in the sight of his Lord

You could pin this rug on the wall in the qiblah direction or somewhere wehre you might being able to read from it, that would be a better and safer use than using it and maybe stepping on one of His names.

Comment: Jazakallah, I will do that inshallah.

Answer (score 0):

Better not use it, as the prayers (or their translations) would be on the floor and under your foot. Buy a regular prayer mat if you are offering prayer at a place which is not tahir.